# Why does this query run so much longer than the sum of the subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can a query like the following take over sixteen hours to run? (We stopped execution to research optimizations, but none of us are DB experts.)  It seems like it should be super-simple to perform the set-based exclusion, right?

```
SELECT 
   field 
FROM
   (subquery that returns 1173126 rows in 20 seconds)
WHERE
   field NOT IN (subquery that returns 3927646 rows in 69 seconds)
```

What else should I include in this note to arm you with enough info to help?

(The actual query follows in case there's something tricksy and specific about it that's causing the problem.)

```
SELECT blob FROM (
      SELECT a.line1 + '|' + substring(a.zip,1,5) as blob
      FROM registrations r
      JOIN customers c ON r.custId = c.Id
      JOIN addresses a ON c.addressId = a.Id
      WHERE r.purchaseDate > DATEADD(year,-1,getdate())
      GROUP BY a.line1 + '|' + substring(a.zip,1,5)) sq
WHERE blob NOT IN (
      SELECT a.line1 + '|' + substring(a.zip,1,5) as blob
      FROM registrations r
      JOIN customers c ON r.custId = c.Id
      JOIN addresses a ON c.addressId = a.Id
      WHERE r.purchaseDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-5,getdate()) AND DATEADD(year,-1,getdate())
      GROUP BY a.line1 + '|' + substring(a.zip,1,5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be searching for the addresses that have purchases within the last year but not within previous 5 years.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.line1, SUBSTRING(a.zip, 1, 5)
FROM    addresses a
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  c.addressId
        FROM    customers c
        JOIN    registrations r
        ON      r.custId = c.id
        AND     r.purchaseDate > DATEADD(year, -1 ,getdate())
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    customers c
        JOIN    registrations r
        ON      r.custId = c.id
        JOIN    addresses ai
        ON      ai.id = c.addressId
        WHERE   r.purchaseDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-5,getdate()) AND DATEADD(year,-1,getdate())
                AND ai.line1 = a.line1
                AND SUBSTRING(ai.zip, 1, 5) = SUBSTRING(a.zip, 1, 5)
        )
```

This query cares of the duplicates of `line1, zip` on addresses with the different ids. Are you having such duplicates?

Comment: Yeah, we're finding "new" customers and there are duplicate line1, zip combinations over the IDs.

Comment: @clweeks: so if there was a purchase `3` years ago from the same address but with different `id`, it doesn't count as new, right?

Comment: Correct.  Someone else in the household may have made the purchase (or their data were keyed poorly) and we're looking for addresses/households that have made new purchases (where 'new' includes people who bought over five years ago, but not since).

Comment: Yeah, it runs in ~19 seconds and returns 852238 rows.  My team-mate is reading up on EXISTS (which we don't use...yet!).  Thanks a ton for the help, by the way!

Comment: @clweeks: give him this link to read (which addresses this very problem): http://explainextended.com/2009/06/17/efficient-exists/

Answer (score 2):

You may not realize this, but a NOT IN statement gets converted to an IF statement by the query engine. So, in your example, it is building a giant IF statement with all those rows (3.9M). Then it has to evaluate each of the IF conditions to see if the value exists. It's no surprise it's taking 16+ hours to run.

You would be much better trying to find a way to convert this to an EXISTS, or perhaps a join.

Comment: This does not evaluate each of the `IF` conditions or even build them all. This is called semi join and there is a variety of algorithms to execute it.

Comment: Before I posted here, I was pawing through the execution plan (which I don't *really* know how to use) and found the "Left Anti Semi Join" in the query I had and figured that was something I needed to research but there's so much to get done that finding time to read up on everything I'd like to is tough.

Comment: @Quassnoi - thank you for the correction. My understanding was that an IF statement is created. Does it do this if the number of rows is small, and then a semi join for larger numbers of rows?

Comment: this is actually anti join (`NOT IN`), not semi join (`IN`). An anti join is a synonym for `NOT IN` operation. As with a plain join, there are different algorithms to execute it: `nested loops anti join` (your if conditions but stopping on the first match), `merge anti join`, `hash left semi join`, `hash right semi join`; all parallelizable with different reducing algorithms; all with optimizations for sequential access which may or may not be applied. What exactly happens is only shown in the plan.

Answer (score 1):

The second subquery is getting run once for each row in the first subquery.

Which means, estimated completion time would be around (1173126 * 69) = 80945394 seconds

Which is roughly 154 years...

After you added the actual query, the best thing for you to do is to optimize the two queries by adding indexes to the tables. I can't tell you exactly which indexes to add but there are plenty of good articles on choosing correct indexes for tables.